# integration by substitution, if substituted by a function.

Tags: integration

All the other proofs I have saw rely on $\int f(\phi(x))\phi'(x) \,\mathrm{dx} = \int f(u)\,\mathrm{du}$, hence $\int f(x)\,\mathrm{dx} = \int f(\phi(u))\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{du}}\phi\,\mathrm{du}$

To me this means I can sub: $\mathrm{dx} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{du}}\phi(u)\,\mathrm{du}$.

However this doesn't seem to be true in my case: if I want to substitute $\cos(u)= \frac{x}{a}$, then dx becomes: $\mathrm{dx}=-a\,\sin(u)\,\mathrm{du}$. I can't explain this with the formula above.

Comment: If $x=a/\cos (u)$ then $dx \neq a \sin(u) du$.

Comment: yea, I had a little twist. It's $\cos(u)=\frac{x}{a}$ To be clear, I've got a function $f(x)$. If I chose x = $a\,\cos(u)$, dx should become $\mathrm{dx} = -\sin(u)\,a\,\mathrm{du} $. Just wondering

Comment: Seems like I'm multiplying one side by $\frac{\mathrm{dx}}{\mathrm{dx}}$ and the other by $\frac{\mathrm{du}}{\mathrm{du}}$

Comment: The little twist changes the derivative significantly as $f(x)$ and $1/f(x)$ are different functions. You'll need to use the chain rule.

Comment: This is clear to me, I just understand how explicitly. I've got $\cos(u) = \frac{x}{a}$.  It strikes me as I can write $\cos(u)\frac{\mathrm{du}}{\mathrm{du}} = \frac{x}{a}\frac{\mathrm{dx}}{\mathrm{dx}}$. What would easily explain with it's $-\sin(u)\,\mathrm{du}= \frac{1}{a}\,\mathrm{dx}$

Comment: $du/du=dx/dx=1$ so you're not actually doing anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first kind of substitution most students learn is the one you describe first:  in an integral of the form $\int f(\phi(x)) \phi'(x)\,dx$, you can replace $\phi(x)$ with $u$ and $\phi'(x)\,dx$ with $du$ to get $\int f(u)\,du$.  If the answer to this last integral is $F(u) + C$, then the answer to the original is $F(\phi(x)) + C$.  To express this, people write $u = \phi(x)$ and $du = \phi'(x)\,dx$, and then
$$
\int f(\phi(x)) \phi'(x)\,dx = \int f(u)\,du = F(u) + C = F(\phi(x)) + C.
$$
It is justified by the chain rule:  if $d/du(F(u)) = f(u)$, then by the chain rule $d/dx(F(\phi(x))) = f(\phi(x)) \phi'(x)$.

But there is a second version of substitution that is essentially a backwards version of this: in an integral $\int f(x)\,dx$, you can replace $x$ with $\phi(u)$ and $dx$ with $\phi'(u)\,du$, to turn the integral into $\int f(\phi(u)) \phi'(u)\,du$.  If the answer to this integral is $F(u) + C$ *and* $\phi$ is invertible, then the answer to the original integral is $F(\phi^{-1}(x)) + C$.  To express this, you would write $x = \phi(u)$, $dx = \phi'(u)\,du$, $u = \phi^{-1}(x)$, and then
$$
\int f(x)\,dx = \int f(\phi(u)) \phi'(u)\,du = F(u) + c = F(\phi^{-1}(x)) + C.
$$
For a more complete explanation of why this is justified, see my book *Calculus: A Rigorous First Course*, Section 8.4: Substitution with Inverse Functions.

I think you are probably doing the second version of substitution, although it's a little hard to tell, since you haven't said what integral you are solving.

Comment: I solved $\int_0^a a\,\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2}\,\mathrm{dx}$

Comment: So your substitution was $x = a\cos u$, $dx = -a\sin u\,du$, $u = \cos^{-1}(x/a)$, yielding $\int_0^a a \sqrt{1-(x/a)^2}\,dx = \int_{\pi/2}^0 a \sqrt{1-\cos^2 u}(-a\sin u)\,du$.  For definite integrals, the substitution is easier to understand.  If you started with the second integral, then you could use the first kind of substitution (justified by the chain rule) to convert it to the first integral.  So the two integrals are equal.